# QUEUE and 'IF' 'ELSE' 'WHILE' statements from scratch and running functions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, queue, game-engine

I'm making a game engine in javascript, and needed some way to code some actions.

The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <script>
var engine={}, actions={}; engine.atomStack=new Array();
events = {
    1: ["action1|5","action2|2;2","action1|2"],
    2: ["action2|5;2","action2|2;2"],
    3: ["action2|5;2","action1|2"] };

engine.runatomStack = function(){
    while(engine.atomStack.length > 0){
        var actionToRun = engine.atomStack.shift();
        actionToRun[0](actionToRun[1]);  } };

eventActivate = function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events[event].length ; i++) {
        var actionAndParam = events[event][i].split('|');
        translateActions(actionAndParam[0],actionAndParam[1]);  } };

engine.action1 = function( param ) {
    console.log("executed action 1, param "+param[0]); }

engine.action2 = function( param ) {
    console.log("executed action 2, params "+param[0]+" "+param[1]); }

actions.action1 = function( param ) {
    var params = param.split(';');
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.action1,params]); }

actions.action2 = function( param ) {
    var params = param.split(';');
    params[1]=parseInt(params[1],10)+2
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.action2,params]); }

translateActions = function(action, param) { actions[action](param); };
</script> </body> </html>
```

Something happens, and I need to run the actions inside an event. I call eventActivate passing the event that should happen. The function translateAction read this information and calls the function that set up the actions. My logic is based that a level contain events, an event can contain actions, and each different action contain atoms.

Example: at some point you call eventActivate(1) and that will push the relative events on the stack. Then from time to time the engine is used and calls engine.runatomStack() to execute whatever is there.

```
//engine.atomStack is Array [  ]

eventActivate(2)
//engine.atomStack is Array [ Array[2], Array[2] ]

engine.runatomStack()

//prints:
//   "executed action 2, params 5 4" example.html:18
//   "executed action 2, params 2 4" example.html:18

//engine.atomStack is Array [  ]
```

Ok, so my engine start to grow and all and now I think I need to add IF/ELSE statements and WHILE/BREAK loops. I have some ideas on implementation but wanted help to what's works best using this queue. Sorry if it's duplicate, but couldn't find help using Google.

I thought something like, if I had events:

```
4: ["action2|5;2","IF|condition","action2|2;2","END|"]
5: ["action2|5;2","IF|condition","action2|2;2","ELSE|","action1|2","END|"]
```

I'm not sure how exactly to go, what's works best...

Link to jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/e3b0kocc/

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you need to use `if/else` and `while/break` for? Are you asking how to run just some of the actions in the queue instead of all of them?

Comment: Yes! I thought I would make a simple game but then some ideas came: if I already talked with character A, character B should say something different. And I suddenly needed a way to have this option to run some actions and not other. The IF statement would be a queuable action itself.

Comment: Just for your intrest: I would use objects instead of arrays. Then you can get rid of the split function(strings).

Comment: Buy why are you not making it an object oriented? If you would make it use observer pattern then you could code your game much easier. If you want to have more decoupling maybe the hexagonal architecture would fit in your needs. Some examples: http://hexagonaljs.com Nevertheless your case fits smoothly into object observer/trigger pattern. And then such if/else while/break things you would have implemented into particular object.

Comment: Right now I store info from the game in json files, because it's easy to read, understand and manipulate. I've read some about the observer pattern but have no clue on what you are saying. Also for easyness, understand that the argument of IF will can call a function called evalCondition("condition"). My code editor uses visual language and each action is added in a graphic list. Also IF and the others I'm suggesting I want to implement as action, but right now they manipulate the stack in the loop. The observer/pattern can be used in the HID part of code: the one that reads gmpad, kbord, toch

Comment: I need only a nested IF statement in a fifo, damn, I've seen this a thousand times, how people implement this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I have a implementation that can solve some stuff, but I think I can't put an if inside another if, which is a problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <script>
var engine={}, actions={}; engine.atomStack=new Array();
events = {
    1: ["action1|5","action2|2;2","action1|2"],
    2: ["action2|5;2","if|true","action1|5","else|","action2|2;2","end|"],
    3: ["action2|5;2","action1|2"] };

engine.runatomStack = function(){
    while(engine.atomStack.length > 0){
        var actionToRun = engine.atomStack.shift();
        actionToRun[0](actionToRun[1]);  } };

eventActivate = function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events[event].length ; i++) {
        var actionAndParam = events[event][i].split('|');
        translateActions(actionAndParam[0],actionAndParam[1]);  } };

evalCondition = function( param ){
    return false
}

engine.if = function( param ) {
    if ( evalCondition(param)) {
        var removeActions = false
        for (var i = 0; i < engine.atomStack.length ; i++) {
            if(engine.atomStack[i][0] == engine.else) {
                removeActions = true
            }
            if(engine.atomStack[i][0] == engine.end) {
                return
            }
            if(removeActions == true){
                engine.atomStack.splice(i)
            }

        }
    } else {
        var actionToRun =[0,0]
        while(engine.atomStack.length > 0 && 
              actionToRun[0] != engine.end &&
              actionToRun[0] != engine.else ){
        var actionToRun = engine.atomStack.shift();
        }
    }
}

engine.end = function () {}

engine.else = function () {}

engine.action1 = function( param ) {
    console.log("executed action 1, param "+param[0]); }

engine.action2 = function( param ) {
    console.log("executed action 2, params "+param[0]+" "+param[1]); }

actions.action1 = function( param ) {
    var params = param.split(';');
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.action1,params]); }

actions.if = function( param ) {
    var params = param.split(';');
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.if,params]); }

actions.else = function( param ) {
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.else,'']); }

actions.end = function( param ) {
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.end,'']); }

actions.action2 = function( param ) {
    var params = param.split(';');
    params[1]=parseInt(params[1],10)+2
    engine.atomStack.push([engine.action2,params]); }

translateActions = function(action, param) { actions[action](param); };
</script> </body> </html>
```

It can be tested it by running

```
eventActivate(2)
engine.runatomStack()
```

Modifying evalCondition return value for true will reach different result. Can someone modify the engine.if code to allow if inside if?